# using enum with large set of items c#

Tags: c#, iis, enums, enumeration, enumset

h every body 
im using enum in c#.net and my set of data is about 300 items 
in iis on windows 10:
when i use enum like this:

```
enum EnumSet{
   item1,item2,... item300
}
switch enumset{
 case EnumSet.Item1:
    {
       //Do something
       break;
    }
...
}
```

the Result is wrong
and when i use like this

```
enum EnumSet{
   item1=1,item2=2,... item300=300
}
switch enumset{
 case EnumSet.Item1:
    {
       //Do something
       break;
    }
...
}
```

the answer change and also is wrong to :-)

*i try to trace problem in iis express its work correctly on that and program always happen when i am testing on iis* 
can every body help me?

Comment: 1. Switch(enumset)  ..braces missing

Comment: thank you my friend in the code i have no error and use switch with braces

Comment: Change the  "IIS Express" to Local host from Project Properties and debug the code and trace out the issue.

Comment: can you explain how?

Comment: If you are working on VS2013 or VS 2015.
1. Right click on the Project> Select <<Properties>>
2. In properties Window   ==> Select <<Web>>
3. From the servers section select <<Local IIS>>
4. Place Debugger at Switch
Run the code

Comment: Obviously first `EnumSet` start at **0** and the second one start at **1** so actual value would be different. `Item2` value is **1** in first case and **2** in second case.

Comment: **Result is wrong** does not tell us the problem or what you observe and what you get. Please be specific.

Comment: in case option going to wrong answer and doing wrong work

Comment: @Phil1970 
I'm not working with value of Items I'm just using them for conditional of switch case

Comment: It is very unlikely that the compiler would generate bad code and if it it the case, then you should write minimal program and send it to Microsoft. Both Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 have a button for feedback in the upper right side of the IDE.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

my program solved
i just add new application in iis and problem sovled

Answer (score 0):

I have tried in Dotnet Fiddle. Please try to parse if you are sending an int value.

```
enum EnumSet {item1=1,item2=2,item4,item300=300};
    public static void Main()
    {

        string enumset=Console.ReadLine();
        int e= int.Parse(enumset);

        switch(e) {
            case (int)EnumSet.item1:
            {   
                Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

OR

```
EnumSet e= (EnumSet)int.Parse(enumset);

        switch(e) {
            case EnumSet.item1:
            {   
                Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: sry my friend does not work
the enumset defined as EnumSet